# OpenLDAP replication error

Tags: debian, openldap, replication

I have 2 OpenLDAP servers with replication activated and everything used to work fine.
A few days ago, the "replica" account's password expired. And since then I was unable to make replication work again. I tried changing password, deleting/recreating the account, unsuccessfully.

I noticed a strange thing, I use a software to read my LDAP data and, when I change the password of the “replica” account, it’s different on my 2 servers. (see screenshot)

[replica_passwords_screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2Gn2.png)

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Edit :

slapd.log shows these two errors (alternatively)
`ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (49)` or `ldap_sasl_bind_s failed (-1)`

EDIT2 :

ldapsearch from replica to main works

ldapsearch from main to replica throws this error : `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I deleted everything from replica and made a clean install.
Works fine now.

More details here : https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/nqgsp0/openldap_replication_error/